# Floating point number is rounding off in C

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

i started learning `c`. Today, while i am working on a program, i found an interesting thing and i made another small program (similar to my issue) to check it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float num1=867.0;
    float num2=.6921;
    printf("sum = %.4f \n",num1+num2);
    return 0;
}
```

if i run the above program, i am getting `867.6921` as the answer. but if i changed the `.4%f` to `%f` the answer is changing to **`sum = 867.692078`**. why's the change in the output? Also, is there any way that i can get the answer without using the `.4%f`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: awesome thank you @yano

Comment: By the way, changing the `float` types to `double` produces the answer you expect.

Comment: @BooRadley it gives me `867.692100`. but the answer i need to get is `867.6921`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float` type has about seven digits of precision (can be anywhere from 6-9 digits).  One alternative is to use `g` instead of `f`.  This fixes the number of precise digits in the number, not just those after the decimal.

```
  printf("sum = %.7g \n",num1+num2);
```

This produces output

> sum = 867.6921

and will always give seven digits of precision for any input.  Number formats would be like :

> 0.000000E+07
>   0000000
>   000000.0
>   00000.00
>   0000.000
>   000.0000

...etc

Comment: @buggenerator I was guessing here from your comments, but was this actually your question?  How to fix the number of precise digits in `printf`?

Comment: Yeah. should've asked like that @J...

Comment: http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/

Answer (score 2):

> but if i changed the .4%f to %f the answer is changing to sum = 867.692078

`printf` rounds the result to that many digits after the floating point you specified, the default is `.6`. While rounding, it uses the current [floating point rounding mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/FE_round), the default is round to the nearest.

Comment: that makes sense. thank you so much!
i have another question if that's alright. in my program i am trying to convert a string to a floating point number. is there any way of doing the above without `.4%f` since the user doesn't know how many numbers are there after the decimal.

Comment: ...I don't think this is the point of confusion.  This is a floating point representability issue.  Naively we would expect `867.692100`, but that value is not representable as a `float`.

Comment: @J... the output should be 867.6921 rather than 867.692100. is there any way of getting it?